# Cannot move out of `req` because it is borrowed

Tags: rust

I'm playing with Rust and [tiny-http](https://github.com/frewsxcv/tiny-http). I've created a function in which I'm messing with the headers of request and then sending response:

```
fn handle_request(req: Request) {
    let headers = req.headers();
    // working with headers
    let res = Response::from_string("hi");
    req.respond(res);
}
```

It fails with error:

```
main.rs:41:5: 41:8 error: cannot move out of `req` because it is borrowed
main.rs:41     req.respond(res);
               ^~~
main.rs:27:19: 27:22 note: borrow of `req` occurs here
main.rs:27     let headers = req.headers();
                             ^~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

So I kinda understand that `req.headers()` accepts `&self` which performs borrowing `req` and `req.respond()` "moves" `req` since it accepts `self`. I'm not sure what I should do here, can someone help me understand that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to make sure the borrow ends before you move the value. To adapt your code:

```
fn handle_request(req: Request) {
    {
        let headers = req.headers();
        // working with headers
    }
    let res = Response::from_string("hi");
    req.respond(res);
}
```

The borrow will only last for the block at the top of the function, so after the end of the block you're free to move `res`.

Comment: That does not remove the borrow, it just drops the value.

Comment: @SteveKlabnik What about the example in the docs? `drop(mutable_borrow)`?

Comment: That's specific to RefCell, which does run-time borrow checking rather than compile-time. That example is very poor :(

Comment: Ah. The example catered to my wishful thinking. Makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

Just quote req

```
fn handle_request(req: Request) {
    // add "&" before req
    let headers = &req.headers();
    // working with headers
    let res = Response::from_string("hi");
    req.respond(res);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was scrambling my brain and found that you can just convert that borrowed response to owned. Using `req.headers.to_owned()`